# Copy paste multiple cells at one go

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I'm using the below code to copy paste a specific range of cells to another sheet..

```css
sht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = comp.Range("B" & i).Value
sht.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(0) = comp.Range("C" & i).Value
sht.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(0) = comp.Range("D" & i).Value
sht.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Offset(0) = comp.Range("E" & i).Value
sht.Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Offset(0) = comp.Range("F" & i).Value
sht.Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Offset(0) = comp.Range("G" & i).Value
sht.Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Offset(0) = comp.Range("H" & i).Value
sht.Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Offset(0) = comp.Range("I" & i).Value
sht.Cells(Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Offset(0) = comp.Range("J" & i).Value
sht.Cells(Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Offset(0) = comp.Range("K" & i).Value
sht.Cells(Rows.Count, 11).End(xlUp).Offset(0) = comp.Range("L" & i).Value
```

Is there anyway to do it in a single line?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: If the **source** and the target areas are rectangular, you can use range definitions for the **input** and the **output** (e.g. something like `B2:L10`).

Comment: Yes your right, however, i'm facing error while trying this it in "End(xlup).offset".

Comment: I tried something like this
sht.Range(Cells(Rows.Count, 11),Cells(Rows.Count, 11)).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = comp.Range("B" & i & ":L" & i).Value and got Object range method failed error :(

Comment: If you share the error message, someone may be able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
sht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).resize(1, 11) = _
    comp.Range("B" & i & ":" & "L" & i).Value
```

Comment: That works nicely :)
sht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(1, 11) = wip.Range("B" & i & ":" & "L" & i).Value
        sht.Cells(Rows.Count, 12).End(xlUp).Offset(0).Resize(12, 21) = wip.Range("N" & i & ":" & "W" & i).Value
I'm trying to copy another set of cells but not working as expected..
Am I using the resize method rightly?

Comment: The second is only 10 columns wide so .resize(1, 10) not .resize(1, 21). Resize(1, 10) means reshape the target to receive 1 row x 10 columns of data which corresponds to N:W on a single row.

Comment: Yep got it :)
sht.Cells(Rows.Count, 12).End(xlUp).Offset(0).Resize(1, 10) = wip.Range("N" & i & ":" & "W" & i).Value
Learned something new today woo hoo!! Thank you again ;)